# How do I make this piece of code incorporating functions, for and while-loops run well?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a text-based-RPG, but I'm having trouble with input. I'm stumped at making a function which is supposed to separate two arguments from a string with a keyword and an item, (for example: use item, take item...) however, for some reason, it keeps repeating the same over and over.

My code:

```
def console(input):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        z = 0
        argument1 = ""
        argument2 = ""
        for x in input:
                if input != " " and y != 1:
                        argument1 += input
                elif y != 1:
                        y = 1
                else:
                        argument2 += input
        print argument1
        print argument2

console("use item")
```

The output I receive when I run the code is this: use itemuse itemuse itemuse itemuse itemuse itemuse itemuse item

I have no idea why 'use' and 'item' are on the same line, as well as why it is repeated a total of eight times.

Comment: Rather than link to code, please paste it here and properly format it by hitting the `{}` button.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Vote to approve the edit.

Comment: I notice that you're initializing the variable `x`.  There's absolutely no reason for doing this. I'm assuming that you don't realize that x is assigned consecutive string values from the (poorly named)  `input`.  In python, for loops don't work the same way as for loops in c/c++/java.  If you _want_ x to be assigned numerical values,  I would do `for x in range(len(input)):`

Answer (score 3):

The `split()` string method already does what you are trying to do:

```
>>> arg1, arg2 = 'use some item'.split(' ', 1)
>>> arg1
'use'
>>> arg2
'some item'
```

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
for x in input:
```

So if input is 'use item' you would loop 8 times (u, s, e,  , i, t, e, m [try print x])
And then you add input to argument with

```
argument1 += input
```

So you add input 8 times to argument.
Why they are added together is because you don't have a '\n' at the end.

Comment: also, OP, it's not a good idea to use keywords as variables. In this case `input`.

Answer (score -1):

It is being repeated 8 times because you are passing in 8 characters. I would suggest breaking up the string into its arguments before entering the for loop.